# NgRx store.select does not working with pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-store

I am trying to select from `store` and use `pipe` with `take()` and `flatMap()` functions.

Here is some code:

```
 this.userState.subscribe(item => console.log("without pipe"));
```

The above code perfectly works; But the one below doesn't and subscribe method is not called:

```
this.userState.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(item => console.log("with take and flatmap"));
```

Same issue if I use`flatMap()` method inside pipe. Can't seem to figure out what is wrong.
Here is the link to the code I pushed to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5zchap)

The above code is in `component2.component.ts` file
Kindly help.

Comment: It is working as expected. Since you have `take(1)`, it is only taking the first value and completing. Change that value to `10` or other number and see the output.

Comment: what about flatMap() then?

Comment: Also working with `flatMap()`. [flatMap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) must return an observable, so based on your requirement make sure to return an observable. For example, try `this.userState.pipe(flatMap(x => of(x)))`.

Comment: take(1) is working but is triggered by the state changes that happens before you dispatch your actions

Comment: yup everything makes sense now. thank you @Nikhil

Comment: You're welcome @ApurvKamalapuri. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

take(1) is working but is triggered by the state changes that happens before you dispatch your actions

Pipe needs to return something. Try this out:

```
this.userState.pipe(map(data => data)).subscribe(item => console.log("with take and flatmap"));
```

Comment: [take()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/take) also returns a value, an observable which emits first _n_ values.

Comment: I know, but only once and since he used 1

Comment: Yes, but using `map()` isn't the solution. It isn't an alternative for `take()`. Your answer should explain why OP's code isn't working.

Comment: take(1) is working but is triggered by the state changes that happens before the dispatch is done. So yeah thats an alternative